# How do I display a metafield property only if the field is filled, else hide it?

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid

This code snippet should display the metafield only if the field is filled.

```
{%- if line_item.properties != empty -%}
<ul class="CartItem__PropertyList">
{%- for property in line_item.properties -%}
{%- assign first_character_in_key = property.first | truncate: 1, '' -%}
{%- if property.last == blank or first_character_in_key == '_' -%}
{%- continue -%}
{%- endif -%}
<p class="CartItem__Variant">Ringgröße: {{ property.last }}</p>
{%- endfor -%}
</ul>
```

Comment: This code should display line item property in cart page.

Comment: `{%- if line_item.properties != blank -%}` use blank instead of empty in liquid.

Answer (score 1):

```html
{%- if product.metafields.meta_field.meta_field != blank -%}
     {{ product.metafields.meta_field.meta_field }}
{%- endif -%}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).